# Ask on SO/SU first, move to Area51 when live?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I have some questions which I could really use answers to now, that the best place to ask would be [area51 Stack GIS](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems), which is not yet live. Is it okay to ask them now on Stack Overflow or Super User in the hopes they might generate an early answer I can use now, and then tag them for moving when GIS does open up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO the best recourse of action is to continue to ask them at Stack Overflow until the site is live. While the site *is* fully committed, Area51 is still in Beta, and it might be a little while before Stack GIS becomes a live site.

Besides, as you said, you could really use answers **now**. So, ask away! (On StackOverflow)

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable guideline. You have to use the network as it exists *now.* Not as someone proposes it to be in the future. Otherwise, we'll never get anything done.

Comment: ok, thank you. It's what made sense to me but didn't want to inadvertently transgress current practice.

Comment: @mattwilkie That was very thoughtful of you to ask, and it was a good question. : )