# why area51 is doing it wrong

Tags: discussion, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can it be done the other way around?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94215/can-it-be-done-the-other-way-around)

I realize the title is provocative, so rather than give a rant of why I don't like the way area51 is working, I'll try to give an analogy and some constructive suggestions.

---

One day at lunch break someone came up with the idea for a new kind of rodent.

First it got discussed and then the consensus was "Wouldn't it be great if it were something that likes to eat poison ivy? Kind of like a mouse, maybe."

Then a bunch of people spent the time and effort to design a new rodent from scratch. The name "ivy-mouse" was chosen. There was a PR campaign to attrach more supporters, and then a breeding program was started for the ivy-mice. After the population of ivy-mice reached several thousand (which took several months of work), they were released into the wild.

The ivy-mice were all eaten by owls within 5 days.

Oops.

A loss for all the people who wanted them to succeed.

The lesson here?

**Evolution does not work by synthesis-from-scratch, but instead by mutation and selection.**

---

How could area51 work differently?

Let's do a thought experiment.

Suppose there were 8 incubator / general reference sites (domain names tbd) corresponding to the 8 categories on area51:

- Arts
- Business
- Culture
- Life
- Professional
- Recreation
- Science
- Technology

Each of these categories are broad enough that they should have no problem gathering enough interest for general questions that don't fit into existing stackexchange sites. We already know that the framework can handle large volume: Stackoverflow just passed 2 million questions.

Instead of area51 starting new sites from scratch, let's have the goal to form proposals to select a category of *existing* questions that are posted to the above broad-based sites.

For a given question on the broad-based site, give certain users the power to tag the question with a special tag that corresponds to an area51 proposal. (certain users = people with lots of points who can tag any question; any questioner or any answerer who gets enough upvotes for their question or answer can tag that particular question)

When the corpus of questions with a given tag reaches a sufficient metric (total # of points, total # of questions, total # of participants, total # of participants with points > 500, etc. etc., whatever), fork off a new site and migrate those questions to it.

This way, we can start asking questions *now*, instead of having to wait for a proposal to gather enough interest to reach beta, only to fizzle out because it didn't end up working like we had hoped.

Let the metric for a new site be based on *existing questions* and *existing users* rather than potential interest from potential users.

Comment: You're basically describing Usenet...

Comment: I like the idea, but rewrite the title and get rid of the top half of the post, and the "Let's do a thought experiment." line -- they don't add anything.

Comment: @Heinzi except that you'd still have the SE platform, rules, it'd be Q&A only, etc., so it'd be nothing like Usenet at all.

Comment: This has been suggested before here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94215/can-it-be-done-the-other-way-around

Comment: sigh. great, so this question that has some interest gets closed down as a duplicate of another question left open that got voted down -5.

Comment: That's what happens when you post about mice eating poison ivy.